# How to finish an animation even if its rule is removed?

Tags: css, css-animations

I'm writing code that makes it so that when an element is given a class, it flashes briefly. To do this, I've created an animation from its "highlighted" appearance to its "unhighlighted" appearance, which is applied when the element is given the `.highlight` class.

The trouble is that the `.highlight` class is usually only applied for a very short moment - it's removed well before the animation finishes. The result of this is that the element will use its "unhighlighted" appearance *immediately* once the class is removed. But my goal is that it will finish the animation, gradually transitioning to the unhighlighted appearance, even though the class that applies that animation was removed.

Below is some code that represents the situation I'm dealing with. Try clicking the button once, then click it again before the animation has finished; note that the animation is cancelled and the "unhighlighted" appearance is immediately used.

```css
#foo {
  background: blue;
  color: white;
}

@keyframes unhighlight {
  from {
    background: red;
  }
  
  to {
    background: blue;
  }
}

#foo.highlight {
  animation-duration: 5s;
  animation-name: unhighlight;
}
```

```html
<p id="foo">
Hello!
</p>

<button onclick="document.getElementById('foo').classList.toggle('highlight')">
Click
</button>
```

Since in practice I'm writing in the context of React, I'd prefer to avoid involving JavaScript in the solution here (e.g. only removing the `.highlight` class once it's detected that the animation has finished) - it would be difficult to incorporate into my existing code (really).

Comment: _“it would be difficult to incorporate into my existing code (really)”_ - I think anything else would probably be even more complex - really.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove `.highlight` class using timer. I understand you have not added JavaScript tag but you are already using JavaScript to add and remove class.

See the Snippet below:

```js
var timer = 0;
var stopAnimation = false;
var animationTimer = 5;

function playStopAnimation(){
console.log(document.getElementById("foo").classList.contains("highlight"));
  if(document.getElementById("foo").classList.contains("highlight")){
    if(timer != animationTimer){
      stopAnimation = true;
    }else{
      document.getElementById('foo').classList.toggle('highlight');
      stopAnimation = false;
      timer = 0;
      console.log("Highlight removed");
    }    
  }else{
    document.getElementById('foo').classList.toggle('highlight');
    stopAnimationFn(animationTimer);
  }
}

const stopAnimationFn = (n)=>{
  for (let i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
      setTimeout(() =>{
        console.log(i);
        timer = i;
            if(stopAnimation && timer==animationTimer){
              document.getElementById('foo').classList.toggle('highlight');
              stopAnimation = false;
              timer = 0;
              console.log("Highlight removed");
            }
      }, i * 1000)
    }
}

    function timerSet(i) {
        setTimeout(function(){
            timer=i;
            console.log(timer);
        },1000);
    }
```

```css
#foo {
  background: blue;
  color: white;
}

@keyframes unhighlight {
  from {
    background: red;
    padding-left:0;
  }
  
  to {
    background: blue;
    padding-left:500px;
  }
}

#foo.highlight {
  animation-duration: 5s;
  animation-name: unhighlight;
}
```

```html
<p id="foo">
Hello!
</p>

<button onclick="playStopAnimation()">
Click
</button>
```